# Umbraco CMS ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I need to find existing plugins for Umbraco, and the ones I have found don't have any documentation of how to use them. After I install them under the package section, where are they supposed to be display? Any ideas? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on which plugins you've installed, please specify which ones they are so we can help better.

Comment: I installed this one "Google_Maps_datatype_1.1" from this link: http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/google-maps-location

Comment: Alright, this is a datatype. I think you have a few document types by now. So go edit your document type and add a new property with this Google maps datatype. Then go to the content section and click on a document of that document type, the google maps plugin should be there.